# Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:

Tags: aws-lambda, environment-variables, serverless

i have this code
and mi .env is in the root of the project
with the envs:
RDS_HOSTNAME=xxx

```
service: pic
frameworkVersion: '3'

plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, "dev"}
  region: ${opt:region, "us-east-1"}
  environment:
    RDS_HOSTNAME: ${self:custom.rds.host_name}
    RDS_DB: ${self:custom.rds.db}
    RDS_PORT: ${self:custom.rds.port} 
    RDS_USERNAME: ${self:custom.rds.user_name}
    RDS_PASSWORD: ${self:custom.rds.password} 


custom:
  dotenv:
   path: .env
 
  n: my-app:${self:provider.stage}:${self:provider.region}:api
  base: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
  rds:
    host_name:  ${env:RDS_HOSTNAME}

functions: ${file(./services/events/serverless.yml)}
```

en the log show
Error:
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:

- Cannot resolve variable at "custom.rds.host_name": Value not found at "env" source